# How to see Gmail labels on the actual emails, in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, gmail, google-sync

Is there a way to view the labels from Gmail in Mail.app on an email, while the email is in the inbox, without opening the actual email (like in Gmail)?

The image shows the emails labeled as K, D, and S (on the right bottom corner of each email):
[image]

This image shows how there are no lables shown on the actual emails, while in the inbox, in Mail.app: 
[image]

Comment: So what you are asking is if mails will be labeled in Gmail whilst labeling these emails in mail.app?

Comment: If labeled in Gmail the email can stay in the inbox *or* be moved but, Mail.app it seems to be labeled, the email has to be also moved. Is there a way to to label in Mail.app and keep the email in the inbox, and see that the email is labeled without opening it?

Comment: If someone knows how to fix Macos, here is a similar issue. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390090/how-fix-macos-mail-so-gmail-labels-appear

Answer (score 2):

So, check the following in Gmail:

Open up Gmail 
Click the gear in the top right to open settings 
Goto 'Labels'
Ensure the 'Show in IMAP' checkbox is ticked next to any labels you wish to see as folders in Apple Mail.

I hope this answers your question, and that this is what you where looking for.

Comment: I esited my question to add some clarification because; I think your answer provides a solution to not seeing any representation of the Gmail labels in Mail.app, as seeing them as Mailboxes. Though I'm looking for a solution to how to see the labels on the actual emails without opening the emai. If that makes any sense.

Comment: yeh it dosent help see the label