# How fix MacOS Mail so Gmail labels appear?

Tags: mac, mail.app, catalina, gmail, imap

I recently bought a new MacBook Pro, and set up Mac Mail with my Gmail accounts.  At first, when the mail was being imported, the labels for my emails listed in the list preview section of the Inbox / message browser appeared.  Then, Mac ran an update for 10.15 (Catalina), and all of the labels for my emails listed in the list preview section of the Inbox / message browser ***disappeared***.

I've ensured that the 'Show in IMAP' checkbox is ticked next to all of the labels I wish to see as folders in Apple Mail.  It shows the mailbox but not the labels for the messages listed in the list preview section of the Inbox / message browser.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I've contacted Apple support, but they haven't provided any guidance.

Comment: "Then, Mac ran an update for 10.15 (Catalina)..."  Do you mean to say that you upgraded *to* Catalina?  If so, from what macOS version did you upgrade from?  (it's not automatic like minor updates).  Or were you running Catalina and a *minor update* was applied (like 10.15.1 → 10.15.4).  This makes a big difference because Mail was updated in Catalina.

Comment: Basically, I was running Catalina (off of a new MacBook Pro that I was just running, and installing everything), and after going through the initial set up it ran an update for Catalina -- something 10.15.1 → 10.15.4, as you said.

Comment: Is there any other info I can provide you that might help solve this?  Hope it's possible to solve this problem...  Thanks so much for your help with this -- I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I can’t seem to find where labels worked on Mail.  The “labels”  show up as folders.  Are you saying it doesn’t show up in folders anymore?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, that's not what I meant. I was saying that when I first set up and ran Mail, the first time I was setting up my MacBook Pro, I was able to see the labels in each line of the emails, as they were listed line-byline (segmented by columns), in the Inbox / message browser section. So, for me, I see the Sender, Subject, Inbox-**Account**, Space, Date Sent. I'm saying I used to see Inbox-**Label** -- and that's what I'm trying to get / display. Is that helpful? Thank you again!

Comment: Just checking in. Wondering if you, or any other users, have any ideas about this -- and how I might be able to fix it.  Many thanks!

Comment: I'm now on Sonoma, so this might not apply. But check under View->Use Column Layout. When that is checked, I see a list of messages with info in columns; one of the columns, titled "Mailbox", shows the source of the message and which "mailbox" it's in. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

This label (Inbox-Account) is only visible when you have more than one e-mail account enabled in Mail app (at least on Catalina 10.15.4).

Comment: Thank you! Well, I have more than one email account enabled in the Mail app (yes, I'm using Catalina 10.15.4). But I'm talking about how that originally showed me the Gmail label / folders -- and now no longer does that. Any idea how to get that view back? Thank you!

Comment: I tried to achieve the same result, eventually gave up and switched to Spark - https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1176895641